# VSCode : FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm new with python, I'm working with VSCode and I want to import a csv file but I can't.

here is my code :

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\\Users\\Documents\\test.csv')
print(df)
```

and it gives me :

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Documents\\test.csv'
```

I tried a lot of things and there is no mistakes in the path or file name.
Did someone have an idea to help me ?

Comment: Either escape the backslashes or use raw strings, not both.

Comment: what if you open the file as a text file and see if that succeeds

Comment: I also can't open this fill as a txt file

Comment: So your Documents folder is under Users? Pretty sure you're missing your user folder there. Make sure your path is correct.

Comment: Did you ensure that the file path was correct?

Answer (score 2):

Either escape the backslashes or use raw strings, not both

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Documents\test.csv')
print(df)
```

## Updated Edit

`%USERPROFILE%` will return your current user's profile path, such as `C:\Users\Lenovo` in my case. so your path could be `C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\test.csv`

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(r'%USERPROFILE%\Documents\test.csv')
print(df)
```

Comment: A test this code but it still gives me the same error, but thank you for the information

Comment: @Chandra does your user account have access to that file, like permissions for your account, that the program is ran under. could you try running your python script in an administrator cmd console window?

Comment: yes i have all access and i run my script as an administrator

Comment: i found the issue lol, you were'nt in your user's profile directory, please test my updated code

Comment: I think you found the problem, when I use %USERPROFILE% I have : bash: fg: %USERPROFILE%: no such job. Also I'm totally new with Python so I don't know anything, even how to change the path. I try to learn by myself but it's complicated

Answer (score 0):

maybe this will fix it

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Documents\test.csv')
print(df)
```

Comment: thank you for you answer, i test this code but i still have the same error